# GPS points displaying in the wrong place

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, gps, coordinates, united-kingdom

I'm trying to help a student by importing an excel table of Lats and Longs into Arcmap, but they are displaying in the wrong location - I am also a bit suspicious of the coordinates.  I imported the points as WGS 1984.

They used a Garmin GPS with the settings saying:

1. Position format:  hddd*mm.mmm'
2. Map datum: WGS 84
3. Map Spheroid: WGS 84

An example of the co-ordinates are below.  I have also attached a copy of how the data is showing - the red circle is where the data should be.

I would have expected the Lats to be in the regions of 55.9 and the Longs in the region of -3.0 to -3.1

lattitude, longitude

56.932, -3.355

56.931, -3.356

56.931, -3.359

56.933, -3.362

[image: GPS location error]

Comment: Is it possible to crop your image to zoom in on where the points are displaying? It's a little bit hard to understand/determine where these are erroneously showing up.

Comment: What you've posted could be only partial values. The Garmin said hddd*mm.mmm'. If we posit that the degree values were omitted and 56.932 is the minutes portion that works out to 0.949 degrees, and about where you expect.

Comment: Decimal Degrees should be in 6 decimal places for accuracy example 57.050485, -3.036527 is Ballater, Scotland https://www.google.co.uk/maps/place/Ballater,+Aberdeenshire+AB35,+UK/@57.0487105,-3.0518475,15z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m2!3m1!1s0x4885c49f3b51c4c5:0x805387b3164d41d5